# How to pass parameters to myscript.sh which I need to execute using '/bin/bash'

Tags: bash, shell, bin

How to pass parameters to myscript.sh which I need to invoke using '/bin/bash' as below

`/bin/bash -c myscript.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

or

```
/bin/bash myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

(You don't need the `-c` option)

and inside the script you can retrieve them by:

```
var1=$1
var2=$2
```